# Error processing condition on org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.indexPageTransformer using Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I've added the Open-api dependency to my project but now the application won't start anymore. It gives the error `Error processing condition on org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.indexPageTransformer` which I believe is to do with perhaps some mismatches between versions, but I can't figure out which one to use since I'm already on the latest one.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>-->
<!--   <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>-->
<!--   <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>-->
<!--   <version>${swagger.annotations.version}</version>-->
<!--  </dependency>-->
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MbblueprintbackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MbblueprintbackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image]

Thank you.